# Algorithm time complexity - product of functions

Tags: algorithm, performance, time, time-complexity, computer-science

If I have the following code in C++:

```
int F1(int n, int s) {
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) s++;
return n;
}

int F3(int n, int s) {
for(int i=1; i<n; i*=2) s++;
return s;
}
```

I need to calculate the time complexity of the following expression:

```
F1(n,0) * F1(F1(n,0) * F3(n,0),0);
```

Now, I am a bit confused what I should do in cases such as this. If I calculate what the result of `F1(n,0) * F3(n,0)` is, I get `n*log_2(n)`. The complexity needed for this is `O(n) + O(log_2(n))`. Now, if I calculate what `F1(n*log_2(n), 0)` is, I get that its complexity is `O(nlogn)` I also know that the first function F1 call has a time complexity of `O(n)`.

However, now I am confused. On the left side of the `*`, I have a function call whose complexity is `O(n)`. To the right, I have an expression whose time complexity evaluates to `O(nlogn)`.

**My question is: **

1. Is the final complexity `O(n) + O(nlogn) = O(nlogn)`, or is it `O(n)*O(nlogn) = O(n*nlogn)`?
2. What if the expression had the sign `+` in between them? Would that change anything *with regards to time complexity?*

Comment: O(infinity), since F3 can loop infinitely.

Comment: I think you're very close to understanding this yourself.  In all the normal machine models used for analysis of this type, `*` and `+` both have O(1) i.e. constant run time.  This answers 2. From this you should be able to answer 1. yourself.  You're nearly there.

Comment: Why does `F1` get a second argument? Its value doesn't influence the result that `F1` returns... Are you sure you have it right?

Answer (score 0):

I think what is confusing you is that `F1(n,0) * F1(F1(n,0) * F3(n,0),0)` is *an expression* not an algorithm, and so to analyze we have to think about what an abstract computer would have to do to evaluate it.

`F1` counts from 0 to *n*, its first parameter, and is thus `O(n)`, and it always returns *n*. `F3` doubles an index variable from 1 to *n* and thus runs in `O(log n)` time and it returns the number of times the index was doubled which means *the value* of `F3(n,0)` will also be `O(log n)`.

To evaluate the expression our abstract computer would have to evaluate `F1(n,0)` once and then evaluate `F1(n,0)` again on whatever the subexpressions `F1(n,0) * F3(n,0)` evaluates to. We can evaluate `F1(n,0) * F3(n,0)` in `O(n)` time since `F1(n, 0)` is O(n) and that dwarfs F3's `O(log n)` running time. The value of `F1(n,0) * F3(n,0)` will be some number that grows like `O(n log n)` since `F1(n,0)` always returns *n* and `F3` will return some value that grows like `O(log n)`.

Thus to evaluate the whole expression requires a running time that is like`O(n) + F1( some value that grows like O(n log n), 0 )`, but `F1(n,0)` is O(n) so this reduces to `O(n) + O(n log n)`, or just `O(n log n)`.